# Failure in setting up replies mailbox

Tags: civimail, sparkpost

CiviCRM 5.14.0
I am using the Sparkpost extension
This is a new site in testing phase

I have set my from email address to be: "Site Administrator"  This domain has been verified by Sparkpost and is a working mailbox.

If I set up a mailing and click on Track Replies in the response tab, I get this message:

```
The "Track Replies" option conflicts with the "Reply-To" option. The "Reply-To" option has been disabled.
```

I assume that this is just a warning that the system will not use the "From" email address for the reply.

When the recipient clicks reply in the email client, the reply address looks like this:

r.105.160.ac5032573de28c3c@vietfeir.com

This address obviously does not exist on in my Postfix virtual_users table. I also believe it should be r.105.160.ac5032573de28c3c@ccrmmail.vietfeir.com and use the domain of the From address.

I changed the reply address to r.105.160.ac5032573de28c3c@ccrmmail.vietfeir.com and got this error.

```
An error occurred while sending mail. The mail server responded:  
5.1.1 <r.105.160.ac5032573de28c3c@ccrmmail.vietfeir.com>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table.
 Please check the message recipient "r.105.160.ac5032573de28c3c@ccrmmail.vietfeir.com" and try again.
```

Now, ccrmmail.vietfeir.com is a CNAME that points to sparkpostmail.com but it is still being rejected by my Postfix server.

I'm not sure what to do to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the address to include a local part so VERP. This now works